# Any good C or C++ libraries out there for dealing with large point clouds?

Tags: c++, sdk, point-clouds, lidar

Basically, I'm looking for a library or SDK for handling large point clouds coming from LIDAR or scanners, typically running into many millions of points of X,Y,Z,Colour.  What I'm after are as follows;

Fast display, zooming, panning
Point cloud registration
Fast low level access to the data
Regression of surfaces and solids (not as important as the others)

While I don't mind paying for a reasonable commercial library, I'm not interested in a very expensive library (e.g. in excess of about $5k) or one with a per user run-time license cost.  Open source would also be good.  I found a few possibilities via google, but they all tend to be too expensive for my budget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I second the call for [**R**](http://www.r-project.org) which I interface with C++ all the time (using e.g. the [**Rcpp**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) and [**RInside**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RInside/index.html) packages).

[**R**](http://www.r-project.org) prefers all data in memory, so you probably want to go with a 64bit OS and a decent amount of RAM for lots of data.  The [**Task View on High-Performance Computing with R**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) has some pointers on dealing with large data.

Lastly, for quick visualization, the [**hexbin**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hexbin/) is excellent for visually summarizing large data sets.  For the zooming etc aspect try the [**rgl**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl) package.

Answer (score 6):

Check [Point Cloud Library (PCL)](http://pointclouds.org/). It is quite a complete toolkit for processing and manipulating point clouds. It also provides tools for point clouds visualisation: `pcl::visualization::CloudViewer` which makes use of [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) library and wxWidgets

Since 2011, point clout translation (read/write) and manipulating toolkit has been developed: [PDAL - Point Data Abstraction Library](http://www.pdal.io/)

Comment: I would add that the `CloudViewer` is somewhat 'simple'. If you need to do something fancy, mostly sure you have to go directly to the `PCLVisualizer`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you go have a look at the [R](http://www.r-project.org/) programming language which can link directly to C code, thereby forming a bridge.  R was developed with statistical code in mind but can very easily help not only to handle large datasets but also visualize them as well.  There are quite a number of atmospheric scientists who are using R in their work.  I know, I work with them for exactly the stuff you're trying to do.  Think of R as a poor man's Matlab or IDL (but soon won't be.)

Answer (score 1):

In spirit of the R answers, [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/) also provides a good undeling framework for this kind of thing.

Possibly useful features:

- C++ code base and the Cint c++ interpreter as the working shell. Python binding.
- Can display three dim point clouds
- A set of geometry classes (though I don't believe that they support all the operations that you need)
- Developed by nuclear and particle physicists instead of by statisticians  :p

Answer (score 1):

Vortex by Pointools can go up to much higher numbers of points than the millions that you ask for:

http://www.pointools.com/vortex_intro.php

It can handle files of many gigabytes containing billions of points on modest hardware.

Comment: Vortex is certainly a good engine but the licensing seems pretty expensive and involved from what I can see.

Comment: I don't know how things are now they have been acquired by Bentley, but it could be worth emailing to see what they can do for you.